# Data copy for an android phone application

Tags: php, android, xml, sqlite, flex4.5

I want to know if someone sees what do I do wrong? I try copy data from xml file to sqlite dababase

```
"INSERT INTO RecipeDB (RecipeID, Name, Origin, Category, Recipe, Favorite, Image) VALUES (" + [values from an arrayCollection]+" ) WHERE " arrayCollection[cnt].RecipeID + "  NOT IN RecipeDB.RecipeID"
```

This is my schema last elemnt is blob format, Error tells me: sysntax error near "WHERE". 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. where clause is not allowed in insert statement.
2. if recipeID is autoincrement, then you dont need to mention it in the insert statement
3. make sure that values are in same order as (RecipeID, Name, Origin, Category, Recipe, Favorite, Image)

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a reserved word

```
"INSERT INTO RecipeDB (RecipeID, `Name`, Origin, Category...
```